# Is it safe to add device sensors listener even though no permission has been granted yet?

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
  // do stuff
});
```

Gives the following warning:

> No device motion or orientation events will be fired until permission has been requested and granted.

It **will** work as soon as I ask and user gives the permission, there's no need to re-add the listener.

Is it a safe practise or could it bite me?